# VBA Delete autofiltered rows in linked table

Tags: excel, delete-row, autofilter, vba

I have a linked table where I want to delete rows based on a date. 
I get it to work out all the way to when I want to delete the rows where i get the error message "Delete method of Range Class failed".
What can be wrong here in the end?

```
Sheets("TimeSeries").Select
Range("TimeSeries[#Headers]").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TimeSeries").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, Format(Sheets("Start").Range("C2").Value, "mm/dd/yyyy"))
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(0, 0).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you autofilter statement works correctly, no need to use `Select`, try it this way:

```
With Sheets("TimeSeries").ListObjects("TimeSeries").Range
  .AutoFilter ......
  .Offset(1).Delete
  .AutoFilter
End With
```